# Issue with JQuery pinch zoom

Tags: jquery, image, zooming, pinch

I am working with JQuery and I want to pinch zoom the image.
My code is:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
      $.mobile.metaViewportContent = 'width=device-width';
});
```

Comment: I need help, Please Hurry up

Comment: I m not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have an image and want to get pinch and zoom effect on it

Comment: then what is the relation with width=device-width .

Comment: well i have searched and got that code .. But still it is not working :(

Comment: use jquery touchy plugin
https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy

Comment: Don't want to use plugin .. It is last option to use ..

Comment: because I have had issues with plugin while running app in android ..

Comment: Well checked your given link but it is also not working regarding pinch zoom it is for swipe

Comment: use this code :

http://www.caincode.com/mobile-pinch-zoom-gesture-detection-javascript-jquery/

Comment: searched this one too :(

Comment: just increase scal value on mobileinit , it will work